# Which came first - Chef's Chocolate Salty, or Schweddy Balls?

Tags: south-park, saturday-night-live

I don't know that these dates are accurate, but per [this discussion forum](https://www.tigerdroppings.com/rant/movie-tv/schweddy-balls-or-chocolate-salty-balls/20508029/), the release dates for Chef's "Chocolate Salty Balls" from *Soth Park* and "Schweddy Balls" from *Saturday Night Live* were:

Chocolate Salty Balls - 8/19/98
Schweddy Balls - 12/12/1998

But which really came first? Mostly I ask because it seems odd that such a similar pun would get featured by two major productions so closely in time. Any idea why, or was it just mere coincidence?

Comment: Other than "balls" the puns aren't actually that similar.

Comment: @OrangeDog sure, excepting that in both cases the entire skit falls apart without the pun.

Comment: What’s that got to do with anything? Are you suggesting that one of these is the first recorded skit revolving around a pun on balls?

Comment: @OrangeDog nowhere have I made that suggestion and it is only obvious that both skits which came out at a very similar time rely entirely upon the pun. Without the pun, there is nothing to the skits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That discussion forum was right about the dates.

The original air date for [Chef's Chocolate Salty Balls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chef%27s_Chocolate_Salty_Balls) is August 19 1998.
Episode of Saturday Night Live with Schweddy Balls [aired on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurring_Saturday_Night_Live_characters_and_sketches_introduced_1996%E2%80%931997) December 12 1998.

> The most frequently replayed installment of this sketch, which originally aired on December 12, 1998, featured Alec Baldwin as Christmas treat maker Pete Schweddy, who owned a holiday-themed store called Seasons Eatings. He was famous for his "Schweddy Balls".

---

The theme of Chef's Chocolate Salty Balls is how Sundance Festival has grown to be a large Hollywood event and how it has commercialized.

From "[Where Did The Come From](http://wiki.southparkstudios.nu/wiki/Chef%27s_Chocolate_Salty_Balls#Where_Did_The_Idea_Come_From)" from South Park Studios Wikia,

> The episode is based on how the Sundance Film Festival has grown from a low-budget independent film festival to a large Hollywood event. A couple of years earlier, the Sundance Film Festival rejected Trey and Matt's film Cannibal! The Musical.

So, Chef's salty balls is a reference on how people try to popularize, advertise and sell them in film festivals using their stalls.

*Saturday Night Live*  has a recurring theme [Delicious Dish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurring_Saturday_Night_Live_characters_and_sketches_introduced_1996%E2%80%931997#Episodes_featuring_The_Delicious_Dish) which was introduced in 1996. As a continuation of this theme, Ana Gasteyer wrote a skit named Schweddy Balls to create fun in the Christmas Holiday Season. [Source](https://youtu.be/KQ2rGwIrt2s).

Perhaps it is just a coincidence. I have not found supporting evidence that Schweddy Balls is inspired or copied from Chef's Chocolate Salty Balls.